# object with one indice not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, iterable, gurobi

When i try to optimize the model, i always get object not iterable.

The goal is to fill up the demand with the powerplants a, b, c with minimun cost of fuel.

Is it because i only have one indice? How can I fix this problem?

```
df_demand = pd.read_excel('...')
df_timestep = pd.read_excel('...')
df_fuel = pd.read_excel('...')
m = gp.Model('try1')

demand_model = df_demand['HeatDemand'].copy()
fuel_model = df_fuel.copy()

cost_oil = fuel_model['Oil']
cost_coal = fuel_model['Coal']
cost_co2 = fuel_model['CO2']
cost_gas = fuel_model['Gas']



T = range(len(df_timestep))

Q_a = m.addVars(T, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='heat a')
Q_b = m.addVars(T, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='heat b')
Q_c = m.addVars(T, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='heat c')

Y = m.addVars(T, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='Status Anlage')


m.addConstrs((Q_a[t] <= 150*Y[t] for t in T), name='a Max.Leistung')
m.addConstrs((Q_a[t] >= 60*Y[t] for t in T), name='a Min. Leistung')
m.addConstrs((Q_b[t] <= 150*Y[t] for t in T), name='b Max.Leistung')
m.addConstrs((Q_b[t] >= 60*Y[t] for t in T), name='b Min. Leistung')
m.addConstrs((Q_c[t] <= 221*Y[t] for t in T), name='c Max.Leistung')
m.addConstrs((Q_c[t] >= 88.4*Y[t] for t in T), name='c Min. Leistung')


m.update()
```

and this following part is not iterable

```
m.update()
m.setObjective(quicksum(Q_a[t]*cost_gas[t]+Q_b[t]*cost_coal[t]+Q_c[t]*cost_oil[t]+
                    for t in T), GRB.MINIMIZE)
m.optimize()
```

Comment: Please visit and read https://stackoverflow.com/help . Also use correct upper-case letters in subject and question-text.

Comment: What is `T`? If it's only 1, then you should remove all those generator expressions. Also, please post the error message - it's not possible to help you with the amount of information you provide.

Comment: T is the indice for each timeseries (so for 0:00 then 1:00 ....)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small loop to check the individual data structures:

```
for t in range(T):
    print(Q_a[t])
    print(cost_gas[t])
    print(Q_b[t])
    print(cost_coal[t])
    print(Q_c[t])
    print(cost_oil[t])
```

Or at least check for consistent sizes, e.g.:

```
assert len(cost_oil) == len(T)
```

There is also an issue in the way you formulate the objective. There is a trailing `+`, so it looks like the last summand is missing.